# Time Complexity of a Algorithm Which Runs in lg(n!) Time

Tags: performance, time-complexity

What is the Big-Θ (or lowest Big-O) time complexity of an algorithm which runs in lg(n!) time?

(where lg -> log base 2)

Comment: It's `Θ(lg(n!))`. But you were probably asked in your homework to work out a simpler form, which is very easy knowing that `log(ab) = log(a)+log(b)` (and no, I'm not going to answer your homework).

Comment: It has nothing to do with homework.  I'm looking at the P vs NP problem, and trying to determine *why* my algorithm does as well as it does. ~O(2^n)

Comment: Basically, I'm wondering if O(lg(n!)) is O(2^n).

Comment: Not it's not. Write `n!` as a series of multiplications and with the formula I gave you above, convert it to a series of sums. Then for every `log(k)` assume the higher estimate `log(n)` and calculate the sum. You then get an upper bound to your algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write `lg(n!)` as:

[image]

And now you can approximate it with integrals:

[image]

Finally solve integrals:

[image]

And your answer is:

[image]

**`lg(n!)` has got `O(nlog(n))` complexity**

Comment: Alternatively, you can simply note that (n/2)^(n/2) <= n! <= n^n.